# Using MVC4, is there a way I can add html classes to Html.TextBoxFor generated inputs in C#?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I want to place an attribute, say "[MyVmAttribute]", on a property in my viewmodel, and every HTML.TextBoxFor created on that property should have an html class added to reflect that fact, let's say "class-from-attribute" or something.  My need is actually much more complex than this, but I need to know WHERE to force this "look for an attribute and add a class based on it" functionality.

Important note:

This has nothing to do with validation, so inheriting ValidationAttribute and hijacking the data-attribute rules functionality there seems wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add the classes to your model and bind them to the Textbox?

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = '@Model.MyStyle' })
```

You can also just set it directly if it doesn't have to be dynamic

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "someClass" })
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own editor [Editor Template](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nunos/archive/2010/02/08/quick-tips-about-asp-net-mvc-editor-templates.aspx).

This would mean you would specify instead of `TextBoxFor`, you would go `EditorFor`, and call your custom template.

Then in the template, you would look for your custom attributes `MyVmAttribute`, get the name/value and inject it into either your own HTML textbox `<input type='text' />` or `TextBoxFor`.

Example, in your view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x=>x.MyProperty,"MyEditorTemplate")
```

In your editor template (located in ~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/MyEditorTemplate.cshthml):

```
@model String
//code to get custom attribute (HtmlKeyValueAttribute) out of `ViewData.ModelMetadata`
//and insert it as either
//@Html.TextBox
//OR
//<input type='text' />
//adding the attribute(s) in a foreach possibly
```

Your attribute I would suggest something that can be used multiple times:

```
public class HtmlKeyValueAttribute : Attribute
{
    public String Name {set;get;}
    public String Value {set;get;}

    public HtmlKeyValueAttribute(String name, String value)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Value = value;
    }
}
```